# Leer contenido de un archivo .html en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa que permita leer archivos `.html` utilizando lenguaje  `C`.

El archivo del programa lo lee correctamente, el único inconveniente que presenta es que no imprime el contenido que se encuentra en el `.html`.

En mí `.html` tengo lo siguiente:

```html
Bienvenido a mi archivo .html
```

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( ) {
  FILE * archivo = fopen( "index.html", "rb" );    

  if( archivo == NULL ) {
    perror( "Error en la apertura del archivo" );
    return 1;
  }

  char *contenido = (char *)calloc(200, sizeof(char));

  while( 1 ) {
    fscanf( archivo, "%s", contenido );

    if( feof( archivo ) != 0 ) {
      break;
    }

    printf( "%s\n", contenido );
  }

  fclose( archivo );
  printf( "\nSe ha leido el archivo correctamente...\n" );

  return 0;   
}
```

Comment: [![Imagen Prueba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhOEe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhOEe.png) Eh descargado tu código y lo he ejecutado, no parece que haya ningún problema pdrías checar si el archivo tiene el nombre correcto que estás leyendo

Comment: El archivo solo tiene "Bienvenido a mi archivo .html", no tiene etiquetas html ni nada por el estilo

Comment: @Alvarez Entonces debería ser un archivo **txt** en vez de **html**, ya que no tiene ese formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La primera problema con este código es como usas la funcion `fopen`: `"rb"` significa read binary en inglés que significa leer binario, que es incorrecto. Un archivo de `html` es un archivo de texto, que insinua que necesitas leer texto, con el modo `"rt"`.

La siguente problema es que no tienes el tamaño del archivo, que se puede obtener con las funciones `fseek` y `ftell`: `fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END)` moverá el puntero en el archivo al fin, y `ftell(archivo)` te contará cuántas carácteres en el archivo apunta el puntero del archivo.

La funcion que buscas es `fread`, que leerá el entiro archivo. Este código puede simplificarse como el siguente:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* archivo = fopen("index.html", "rt");
    size_t tamano;
    char* contenido;

    // Move el puntero al fin
    fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END);

    // Cuantas caracteres esta del principio
    tamano = ftell(archivo);

    // Move el puntero al principio, asi que puede leer el archvio
    // del principio
    fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Ahora, contenido siempre sera el tamano correcto
    contenido = malloc(tamano * sizeof(char));

    fread(contenido, sizeof(char), tamano, archivo);

    // Aqui, haz las cosas que quieres hacer con contenido ...

    // Por ejemplo:
    printf("Contenido:\n%s\n", contenido);

    // Esta espacio ya no necesita existar
    free(contenido);

    return 0;
}
```

Cuando yo creí un archivo en la misma carpeta que llamé `index.html` el resultado fue:

```
Contenido:
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hola, mundo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que haya ayudádote.